# Notation: How to express a "set of randomly drawn indices"

Tags: combinatorics, notation, index-notation

This question is about notation. I would like to make clear to the students that one can approximate the mean by randomly drawing a subset of data. I came up with the following:

$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i \\
\approx & \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j \in J_n} x_j  
\end{align}
$$
*Where $J_n$ is a set of $n$ indices, drawn from* $[1..N]$.

I wonder whether there is a cleaner way of expressing this approximation. Maybe I miss a standard notation for "a set of $n$ indices, 'randomly' drawn from $[1..N]$" ?

As a follow up, I'd also like to know how to properly express "a set of $n$ indices, 'randomly' drawn (*without replacement*) from $[1..N]$."

Thank you for suggestions and comments.

---

update (clarification in response to some of the comments below)

We are given a set of $N$ data: {$x_1, x_2, ... , x_N$}. From this set, I want to draw a subset of $n$ data.

Example:

For $n=3$, a possible subset of data is {$x_{43}, x_{19}, x_{87}$}. That is, I draw $n=3$ elements from the set of indices {$1, 2, ..., N$}. Using the notation in the post above, I use the symbol $J_{n=3}$ to denote some set of $3$ indices . 
All indices are equally likely to be drawn.

Optionally we can distinguish the cases "drawing with replacement" and "drawing without replacement"

Comment: What about $\sum_{k=1}^n x_{i_k}$ where $i_k$ is a random variable between $1$ and $N$? PS what do you mean 'without replacement'?

Comment: It depends on how particular you want to be about what "random" means. Random how?

Comment: If $x_i = 2^{2^i}$, I doubt that your method will produce any good result.

Comment: I think virtually all the content involved in what you are literally saying is buried within what is meant by "random". If you simply want to talk about various choices that you could consider, then you're just choosing a subset of indices rather than choosing a **random** subset of indices. My initial reaction is that you're saying "random" when you should be saying "generic" or "arbitrary".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for the comments. I've updated the post.